# Efficiently query Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, redis

I am building a wallet app and I am using redis for caching the current wallet balance of a user. I was asked to retrieve the sum of the entire balance of all users using the application. I have been looking for a way to query redis for this data since it's already cached there.

The keys I used to save them are `user_id-current-balance`. Is there a way I can get all the keys ending with `-current-balance` and then retrieve all the data they hold? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can get all matching keys, then sum the values of the keys in a loop. Use one of the following to obtain the keys:

- [KEYS `pattern`](https://redis.io/commands/KEYS): *O(N) with N being the number of keys in the database*

  This is generally not a performant solution (but if your db is very small, you can test the query cost).
- [SMEMBERS `key`](https://redis.io/commands/smembers): *O(N) where N is the set cardinality*

  Using this technique, you'd create a set at `key` and then add each key holding a user balance (e.g. `user_id_1-current-balance`, `user_id_2-current-balance`, etc.).

Comment: Instead of `KEYS` and `SMEMBERS`, `SCAN` and `SSCAN` are better, especially for large data set.